# Can I use Cloud Pub / Sub to send an email at a later time?

Tags: email, google-app-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

We're trying to implement a queue that contains details about an email recipient and a delivery time at which an email needs to be sent to them. For example, let's say you add a reminder on our app for 1 month later at a specific date and time, we need to send you an email at that time to remind you of whatever you posted on our application.

We can't figure out a way to tell Pub / Sub to run a specific task at a time of our choice. We use App Engine but want to isolate our email scripts to a Google Cloud Function so ideally:

- User saves a reminder on our application and asks to be reminded by email at a later date (this request goes to our Node.js App Engine web service)
- Our web service adds this "task" to Pub / Sub or any other solution that you kind folks recommend. The task includes the user's email address, when the email needs to be sent and the URL that it should call to send the email. The URL should ideally be our Google Cloud Function.
- The task runs until completion, retries if there was any issue reported by our Cloud Function when trying to send the email

We just can't figure out a simple way to do this on GCP. Should we just use CRON on App Engine with a task that runs every 1 minute and looks into our database to find email tasks? The issue with that approach is that App Engine CRON jobs can only call URLs within App Engine and not our Cloud Function. This way, we have to clutter our web service code and also handle issues that can arise when trying to deliver the email. How can we achieve this kind of functionality? Thanks.

Comment: How about having the periodical CRON job publish a message instead of sending the email itself? You can even make it a separate service.

Comment: @danielx That sounds like a good idea! Is that how most other web applications that have similar functionality work?

Answer (score 1):

PubSub does not include a scheduling service. You need to craft this yourself e.g. Use a taskqueue with AppEngine, use CRON on AppEngine to interact with Cloud Functions etc.